# An empty pipe element is not allowed - the Powershell I copied fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I am just trying to fix something to get my BCS external list created. All indications are that the server has too many rows for BCS so here is what I put into the Powershell IDE running as administrator:

```
$bdc = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy
    | Where {$_ -match "Business Data Connectivity"}
    $throttle = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -ThrottleType Connections
        -Scope Global
        -ServiceApplicationProxy $bdc
Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Enforced $false -Identity $throttle
```

Here is the error I got back:

```
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At     D:\Troubleshooting\Powershell\DisableThrottleForBCS\FixToGetWalkthroughForBCSExternalListWorking.ps1:2 char:9
+ | <<<< Where {$_ -match "Business Data Connectivity"}
+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Please help if you can see the error.

EDIT update to original post:

After more research and trials, I got this to work:

```
$bdc = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy  | ? Where {$_.Name -like 'Business Data Connectivity Service'}
$throttle = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -ThrottleType Connections -Scope    Global -ServiceApplicationProxy $bdc
Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Enforced $false -Identity $throttle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work:

```
$bdc = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy  | ? Where {$_.Name -like 'Business Data Connectivity Service'}
$throttle = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -ThrottleType Connections -Scope Global -ServiceApplicationProxy $bdc
Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Enforced $false -Identity $throttle
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
...$_.Property -match...
```

In this case $_.TypeName?

This error comes from the pipe not having a variable to compare against I believe, again not a very clear error message, no shock there!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I am still stuck with same error message as in original post. I have tried the following syntax after the pipe operator:                               Where {$_.TypeName -match "Business Data Connectivity"}     also                                                                  Where {$_.ProcessName -match "Business Data Connectivity"}